# Discord Bot Not Working In getting a random picture

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I tried making a discord bot that sends a random anime image when '$sad' is written in chat. The code is not working, anyone knows how to fix it?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetchData = require("node-fetch");
const client = new Discord.Client();

function getImg() {
  return fetchData("https://waifu.pics/api/random")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.url;
    });
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;

  if (msg.content === "$sad") {
    getImg().then((img) => msg.channel.send(img));
  }
});

client.login(process.env["key"]);
```

Comment: What is the bug? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: @YoungChoi well i change the api and it still didnt work (edited to new api). Im using replit.com to make the bot and yes there is an error message. It includes : logged in as Akvn Bot#4908
(node:630) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Akvn-Bot-JS/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you are using sends `{"message":"Not Found"}`, so of course `data.url` will be undefined.

Looking at [the documentation](https://waifu.pics/docs), you need to use the endpoint `https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu`.

Comment: Thank u my guy! Its my first discord bot and second api project so I got confused in the documentation. Its not fixed thank u for the help!:) @Seblor

Comment: @AkonZ If my solution did not work, can you tell me if the error changed ?

Comment: It worked now, it was a problem with the api as u said. Thank u for the help:)

Comment: @AkonZ If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it so your question is marked as solved.

Comment: I dont know how to accept it but I think I did now, if not lmk how